# How to strore Output of data frame in dropdown format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a task to create cluster report on daily basis.I am able to read the jobs Id and status of each job by Scala code. But I an not able to store the output of data frame in drop down format for each date.

ex

```
 Current DataFrame Output:
   Date    |  Job_Id | job_Status | Run_Time
   20180101|123      |Successful  |1m 
   20180102|234      |fail        |0s

 Required DataFrame Output
 Date
 20180101
     |_123
     |_Successful
     |_1m

 20180102
     |_234
     |_fail
     |_0s
```

Like this there are 100's of jobs running on daily basis. I want to create report of this.

Comment: Spark is a data analytics framework, without any UI. Referring to a UI dropdown element in that context doesn't make much sense and does not help a person trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `saveAsTextFile`to write in file using `mkstring` function, Here is a simple example

```
  val d = Seq(
    ("20180101","123","Successful", "1m"),
    ("20180102","234","fail", "0s")
  ).toDF("Date","Job_Id","job_Status","Run_Time")

  d.rdd.map(x => x.mkString("\n--"))
   .saveAsTextFile("outputFile")
```

Output:

```
20180101
--123
--Successful
--1m
20180102
--234
--fail
--0s
```

But I hope you could save in any other format, so that it becomes easier to read later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I need to create dropdown output. like if I click on particular date it should open its status.